# Is it possible open a URL (Webpage) and then print it from MS Access using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a command button that currently opens a URL based on record information. I can successfully open the webpage from MS Access but I'm unsure if I'm able to send a print command to the web browser.

My code opens up an x amount of webpages as part of a document package, instead of the user going into each document and printing I would like this to be automated.

Code to open the webpage - trim number is an array containing a list of different link extensions

```
For i = 1 To UBound(trimnumber)
    'Open the links
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open "http://trimconnect/SP/view/" & trimnumber(i) 
Next i
```

I don't know how I can then command it to print from MS Access.

Alternatively I was looking into opening those links and saving as a PDF, or opening the links straight into PDF or similar but I have had no luck. Ideally once printed, the window will close but I don't think MS Access can send that command to the browser (I could be wrong!).

Comment: Not by using Shell methods. See if this helps https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-a-macro-to-open-then-print-a-webpage.596387/. Also, printing can be done from WebBrowser control https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print?view=net-5.0. No idea

Comment: @June7 yeah I stumbled across that second link too. Anyway I managed the load a webpage (tested with google.com) into a web browser control and then I was able to print that using a method found here https://www.utteraccess.com/topics/2002165. I came across some other complications but mainly due to my data/url so I think I will have to think of another way. HTML or something else maybe. Guess I'm going to be learning something else new today! Thanks for your input.